New Cabinet Install - Should I Be Worried?
My in-laws have gone through a local contractor to buy and install cabinets. After they started the install process we went over to take a look at things, the contractor was looking to be done with the job in a day or two. Since this is the first time having work like this done, I am wondering if we are being too picky about the issues we found or if the concern is justified. They spent 13k on the cabinets and another 10k for install.
Is there a fix for these issues or should they have him replace them?
Any help would be much appreciated. Below are images of some of the issues.
https://imgur.com/a/M7ptJpY

For that kind of money it should near perfect. Nothing should be split or scratched. That should be repaired or replaced.

Pretty underwhelming quality. Yes, cabinets have to be screwed together, but putting big screws in the face frame (without pre-drilling) is rookie work. This can be fixed with some filler and paint, but I’d be negotiating a discount.

The splits are a big problem. After the first one (because mistakes do happen), the boss should have stopped the new helper and showed them how to pre-drill a hole (if you have two drill/drivers then you use one as a drill and the other as a driver and it only takes a few seconds extra per screw) and how to adjust the drill/driver to not drive the screws too far. Which means there was either nobody experienced on the job or they just don't care. For $10k installation, they really should care.

Can somebody say PILOT HOLE???!!! That's just sloppy work.

DO NOT PAY THESE PEOPLE!   They are hacks and should be ashamed.  Ask the contractor if he would accept that work in his home.   If he says yes, then tell him he obviously has far to little pride in his work or attention to detail to be acceptable to work in your house, or your in-laws.

You are paying for new cabinets, installed properly. Not cabinets that are already scratched up, cracked, misaligned.
There is one cabinet that was put up in the wrong spot on the wall and when relocated to its proper spot left holes exposed on the end, let alone the wood that is mashed from the screw head run in and removed, with no attempt to fill or fix.
Before the cabinets were installed, there were no cracks, now there are. If there were cracks in the cabinets before they were installed, they should have been rejected, just to make a point.
Perhaps some of the cracks can or may be deemed as not violating the strength of the cabinet, some need to be replaced, like the end one with the holes that show on the end. Leave it installed, use it, and let them know that is what you will do, but they will replace it. When the new one or ones.... show up, you will remove the contents of the cabinets to be replaced, they will install the replacement, besides fixing the scarred surfaces in other areas.  Do not let the original installer fix the issues, tell the GC you have no confidence in the previous installer. If they do not have anybody who can on payroll, they need to sub another installer to fix the issue. Hold back half of the payment until they make good. If you have already paid half, pay no more until these items are fixed to your satisfaction.
You hold the keys. Do not settle for inferior work.
(I will probably get called on this one....)
Tell them just like I wrote it. You will do this and this, then you get paid, end of story.
Don't let them tell you what they will do unless it reflects what you want.
I have installed kitchens, bathrooms laundry rooms in new construction, large homes for less money than you are paying, unless the demo of the old cabinets was part of the plan for them to do.
